# Intellij/Bugzilla Integration

Tags: intellij-idea, bugzilla

Does IntelliJ-Idea have a plugin for interacting with bugzilla, like the mylyn plugin for eclipse (task management)?

If it does, what is the name of the plugin?  If it does not, do you have any suggested solutions for using bugzilla with Intellij-Idea.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tracklink might be what you are looking for. Check it out [here](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?&id=142).

Comment: I was able to get Tracklink to work.  It requires a third party application called [Deskzilla](http://almworks.com/deskzilla/overview.html) for the integration to work.  Deskzilla has a "lite" version (free) and a paid version.  I was hoping for direct integration into the tool, without a third party application, but this will work for now.  I'm testing it out with the "lite" version.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR intellij idea 10's task management feature works with bugzilla out of the box. Please try to configure it according to the [idea help guide](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/enabling-integration-with-an-issue-tracking-system.html). I use this integration with JIRA and it works really well. As for third-party plugins I dont like them much because of the support. These plugins might not work when you update from version to version (f.i. as Reformat++ does).

Comment: I tried this option, but Bugzilla is not in the list of supported servers.  I tried each one just to see if it would work, but none of them worked.

Comment: Checked at work. That's true. I hope integration with bugzilla will be released soon.

Answer (score 0):

This is not in the official plugin repo, but https://github.com/nickhristov/bugzilla-intellij-task-provider/ does provide for bugzilla as an option in the Task Servers.  This does work, but self signed certificates cause it to fail with an obscure message about "peer not authenticated".  Following the instructions from here http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Connecting+to+SSL+services and manually adding the self signed key to the default java keystore made it work for me.